# Windows Phone 10: Multiple SplitView.Pane

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app

In my Windows phone application, I'd like to have two `SplitView.Pane`: One on the left and one the right.

I've Added one `SplitView.Pane` to my `SplitView` without any problem, but when I try to add a second `SplitView.Pane`, Visual Studio complains that

> The property Pane is set more than once

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
              CompactPaneLength="0" OpenPaneLength="200">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel Background="Gray">
                <ListView x:Name="listView" Padding="0,5,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid Background="White">
                <WebView x:Name="webProvider"
                 NavigationCompleted="webProvider_NavigationCompleted" />

            </Grid>

        </SplitView.Content>
        <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel Background="Gray">
            <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" Content="test"
                    Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent"/>
        </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>
```

Is there a way around this?

**Answer**

Rowland Shaw had the right idea of putting one SplitView inside another. This is  the XAML I used to implement the arrangement.

```
<SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"  IsPaneOpen="False" 
          CompactPaneLength="0" OpenPaneLength="220">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <StackPanel Background="#555">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" Padding="0,5,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>

            <SplitView x:Name="RightSplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False"   
              FlowDirection="RightToLeft"  CompactPaneLength="0" OpenPaneLength="200">
                <SplitView.Content>
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <WebView x:Name="webProvider"
             NavigationCompleted="webProvider_NavigationCompleted" />

                    </Grid>
                </SplitView.Content>
                <SplitView.Pane>
                    <StackPanel Background="#555">
                        <ListView x:Name="rightListView" Padding="0,5,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </SplitView.Pane>
            </SplitView>

    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>
```

Comment: Why not have a second SplitView inside the first?

Comment: A SplitView has one Content and one Pane element. Setting a second Pane element is invalid, hence the error. A solution would be to Wrap a SplitView in a SplitView. But you could also use a Grid for this with three columns.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: An idea so simple did not occur to me. Can you please write that as the answer so that I can accept it? I'll add the code that I used to my question to help others who face the issue.

Comment: @menawi you can answer for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Areas ... in your Code. You can only have own. If you really want to have two SplitViews. you have to add two controls to your page.